# Getting error when try casting plc values

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion, plc

I'm working on a project which can read plc variables, now i'm getting an error when try to converting a real into an double.

Pic of Visual Studio error:

[image: Pic of Visual Studio error]

Following the method parameters:

[Parameters of method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPkv3.png)

The code:

```
 string totalAdress = "DB100.DBD" + configRecord.getLabelAdress();

                        double value = ((uint)plc.Read(totalAdress)).ConvertToDouble();

                        if (value == 0)
                        {
                            row.Cells[0].Value = configRecord.getLabelName();
                            row.Cells[1].Value = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            row.Cells[0].Value = configRecord.getLabelName();
                            row.Cells[1].Value = value;
                        }
```

Note*: I'm using a timer(3000 ms) to refresh this function so it keeps updating the values, the error only occurs like once a minute..

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What´s the result of `plc.Read(totalAdress)`? Obviously it´s not a `uint`.

Comment: what is `plc`? .

Comment: program is for s7-1200 and s7-1500 plc's.

Comment: Btw im using s7.Net, and as mentioned before, the error only occurs like 1:20 on refresh.

Comment: totalAddress seems string and ConvertToDouble() extension method seems to parse string to double. You got casting exception

Comment: Total adress is indeed the string which contains the adress of the plc-data. This is also the parameter of plc.read(), plc.read is given it answer but im not sure in what datatype that answer is. That answer i want to convert to double but i think it gives an error when its NULL.

Comment: What i currently have:

    double value = ((uint)plc.Read(totalAdress)).ConvertToDouble();

Is also written in the manual of this reference, link below:

https://github.com/killnine/s7netplus/blob/master/Documentation/Documentation.pdf

Comment: Still not fixed:(